# HSQLDB substitute for CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: hsqldb, user-management

According to the [docs](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/accesscontrol-chapt.html#acc_statements), the `CREATE USER` syntax on HSQLDB is:

```
CREATE USER <user name> PASSWORD <password> [ ADMIN ]
```

The statement provides no way to check if the user exists (à la `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS`), and will fail if a user `<user name>` already exists.

Digging a little deeper, I found that existing users can be enumerated with

```
SELECT USER_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS;
```

How can I add this check to a one-liner (i.e. one I can run e.g. via DatabaseManager)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most CREATE statements support IF NOT EXISTS, there is no way to do this for CREATE USER.

Comment: In fact I have moved the user creation into Java code, with a previous check to ensure the user does not exist already (same for a role I also need to create). Too bad `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` is not supported, though.